# Where does ASP.NET Authorization occur?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET web API project, I made a custom class to override the Roles property for the Authorize attribute.

```
public class AuthorizeRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public AuthorizeRolesAttribute(params Roles[] roles) : base()
        {
            if (roles.Length == 1)
                Roles = ((int)roles[0]).ToString();
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < roles.Length; i++)
                {
                    var role = ((int)roles[i]).ToString();

                    if (i == 0) // First role
                    {
                        Roles = role + ",";
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (i == (roles.Length - 1)) // Last role
                    {
                        Roles = Roles + role;
                        break;
                    }
                    Roles = Roles + "," + role;
                }
            }
        }

    }

public enum Roles : int
    {
        User1 = 1,
    }
```

Now assuming that I've called an API but the request didn't have the "User1" role attribute, Where can I set a break point to see the actual checking and comparing of the role that I got from the request with the role that is attached to a certain API. Do I have to write another class that inherent another class?

Answer (score 0):

It would happen at `AuthorizationFilter` section and you should use your attribute in-place of `[Authorize]` attribute either per controller  / per API endpoint/ global. You should put a breakpoint in your custom authorize code block.

Thus once you make a request and it reaches to Authorization, your custom attribute code block should hit just fine. Again, you will have to register your custom attribute to the `config` pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using web api, you need `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`. That is the authorize attribute for ApiControllers. Not the same as for MVC Controller.

Create your customer attribute that extends it, override its `OnAuthorize` method into which you'll put whatever your authorization logic is and decorate your controller action with it. Once action is hit, your breakpoint set in `OnAuthorize` will also get hit.